# Output a specific link in Wordpress post if the single post's category's name contain certain word

Tags: functions, taxonomy

I want to output a specific link in every post, depending on the post's category. For example, if a post is in "travel" category, then the link to https://www.example.com/travelbooking will be displayed in this post. If a post is in "hotel" category, then the link to https://www.example.com/hotelbooking will be displayed in this post.

I tried this code

```php
<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
$firstCategory = '$category[0]->cat_name';

if (strpos($firstCategory, 'travel') !== false) {
    echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/travelbooking">Visit travelbooking</a>';
}

if (strpos($firstCategory, 'hotel') !== false)  {
    echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/hotelbooking">Visit hotelbooking</a>';   
}  

else {
    echo '<a href="https://www.example.com">Visit homepage</a>';
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work, any suggestion?

Comment: I'd recommend you instead add custom `term_meta` to your categories, then pull that data in when you check the categories. Term meta data was added to WP in version 4.4.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the single quotes around the expression otherwise it will be treated as a string.

> `$firstCategory = '$category[0]->cat_name';`

Should be changed to:

```php
$firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
```

Then you can try basic debugging like printing the output of the `$category` and `$category[0]->cat_name`.